# How to run tests in visualstudio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

How do I run the tests written in codeduitest (c# code) in visual studio ?

when i Right-click in a test method, in a test class, or outside the scope of a test class, and then choose Run Tests , it doesn't run the test.Instead it just builds.

Even I tried to run the tests rom TestExplorer.But after clicking on TestExplorer -> Run all tests , it again just builds the solution and doesn't run any script ?

I have Visual Studio 2012 ultimate installed in my machine ?

Comment: Have you tried this with any other kind of test? Just try creating a trivial unit test and then try "Run all tests in solution".

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue. VS was installed on VM and test cases could not be started. Did you install VS2012 on Virtual Machine? If yes, try with real Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .testsettings file. And then rerun the test.

Comment: Did you check if you are getting any errors? You can see the errors in output window...In the output window, select "Tests" in the drop down and run the tests.. See if there is anything written to this window.